# TRegExpr why (.*$) expression works twice on the string?

Tags: regex, delphi

I'm parsing the string with `TRegExpr`. Expression looks like:

```
(.*$)
```

It means it should find the whole string, but after finding it when I use command `ExecNext`, it finds empty string, but the line is over already because of the `$` symbol.

Can someone explain such behavior?

Comment: Does the string contain a newline character maybe?

Comment: Obviously the string contains newlines. Otherwise there would be no question.

Comment: String doesn't contain the newline character. But more likely stema's answer is correct: The $ an anchor, a zero width assertion. It does not match the end of the string, it matches the position before the end of the string (or before a newline that is the last character in the string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because of the `*` quantifier. It will match 0 or more occurrences of the character before. 0 Occurrences means it will match the empty string.

The `$` an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), a zero width assertion. It does not match the end of the string, it matches the position before the end of the string (or before a newline that is the last character in the string).

So what happens?

1. Your regex matches at first the string till the end of the string.
2. The position of the regex engine is after the last character, but before the end of the string. When you call now `ExecNext` it matches the empty string before the end of string.

If you want to avoid this, use the `+` quantifier, it will need at least one character to match ==> `.+$` will find only one match.

Comment: By that argument, the regular expression should match forever because the end of the string is never consumed. By using `+`, the expression will only match lines that end with at least one character, but the intention is clearly to match the remainder of the line, however long it is.

Comment: @RobKennedy. No it will not match forever, because after it matches the empty string it moves it position ahead and see's that it is finished. See [this example on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32aql). match 'a*' on the string "ab". It will match 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the regex expression `.` (a dot) doesn't match a newline. IF you input has a newline, you'll see this behaviour.

Try this:

```
(?s)(.*$)
```

The expression `(?s)` turns on "dot matches newline" for the remainder of the regular expression.